# Java Blackjack OOP

Tags: java, oop, enums, blackjack

I am trying to achieve the best potential of OOP in Java by creating a blackjack game. I have 5 java files so far.

Suit.java

```
enum Suit {

/*
 * Initialize suit values
 */
    HEARTS,
    SPADES,
    CLUBS,
    DIAMONDS;
}
```

Rank.java

```
enum Rank {

    /*
     * Initialize rank and card value
     */

    TWO(2),
    THREE(3), 
    FOUR(4), 
    FIVE(5), 
    SIX(6),
    SEVEN(7), 
    EIGHT(8), 
    NINE(9), 
    TEN(10), 
    JACK(10), 
    QUEEN(10),
    KING(10), 
    ACE(11);


    // Hold card value
    private int cardValue;

    /*
     * Constructor set card value
     * @param cardValue value of card
     */
    private Rank(int cardValue) {
        this.cardValue = cardValue;
    }

    /*
     * This method obtains the card value
     * @return This returns the value of card
     */
    public int getCardValue() {
        return cardValue;
    }
}
```

Card.java

```
public class Card {

    private Suit suit;
    private Rank rank;


    public Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public Rank getCardValue() {
        return rank;
    }

    public Suit getSuitValue() {
        return suit;
    }
}
```

deck.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;


public class Deck {

    private ArrayList deck;

    public Deck() {

        this.deck = new ArrayList();

        for(Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
            for(Rank rank: Rank.values()) {
                Card card = new Card(rank, suit);
                this.deck.add(card);
            }
        }

        Collections.shuffle(deck);
    }

    public ArrayList getDeck() {
        return deck;
    }
}
```

Game.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Deck deck = new Deck();

        for(int i=0; i<deck.getDeck().size(); i++) {

            System.out.println( ((Card)   deck.getDeck().get(i)).getCardValue() + " of " 
            + ((Card) deck.getDeck().get(i)).getSuitValue() );
        }
    }
}
```

Does my design make sense so far? Also how can I call (Rank.java) -> int getCardValue() instead of (Card.java) -> Rank getCardValue()? Do I need to do some polymorphism? extend? I want the int value not the text value.

Thanks!

Comment: This may not be an appropriate question for this site. Having said that, how are you going to handle the potential dual values of the ACE rank, 1 and 11?

Comment: Yes indeed a better place for this question is [codereview.SE.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: As for getting the Rank, simply use `getRank()` and call `getValue()` on the object returned.... or whatever name you give these methods.

Comment: Use generics: `ArrayList<Card>` in your class `Deck`, instead of the [raw type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your direct question, all you need to do is to simply chain methods:

```
Card myCard = new Card(Rank.TWO, Suit.HEARTS);
int value = myCard.getCardValue().getCardValue();
```

The first `getCardValue()` call returns a Rank object, and the next `getCardValue()` get's the rank's value.  But this is confusing to me, two methods with the same name that return different types. Myself, I'd rename Card's `getCardValue()` to be the more straightforward and logical `getRank()` and Rank's `getCardValue()` to the more simple `getValue()`. Then the code would look more logical:

```
int value = myCard.getRank().getValue();
```

As for your other question, "is the design OK", that's too broad for this site, but I think that you're using inheritance fine, that you don't want to over-use inheritance and to stick with composition as you're doing. And also I will say that you need to account for ACE having two possible values, 1 and 11.

For example, possibly something like:

```
public enum Rank {

    TWO(2, 0, false), 
    THREE(3, 0, false), 
    FOUR(4, 0, false), 
    FIVE(5, 0, false), 
    SIX(6, 0, false), 
    SEVEN(7, 0, false), 
    EIGHT(8, 0, false), 
    NINE(9, 0, false), 
    TEN(10, 0, false), 
    JACK(10, 0, false), 
    QUEEN(10, 0, false), 
    KING(10, 0, false), 
    ACE(11, 1, true);

    private int value;
    private int value2;
    private boolean twoValues;

    private Rank(int value, int value2, boolean twoValues) {
        this.value = value;
        this.value2 = value2;
        this.twoValues = twoValues;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int getValue2() {
        // TODO: consider throwing a custom exception if twoValues is false
        return value2;
    }

    public boolean hasTwoValues() {
        return twoValues;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Also I had getCardValue() two times. I just changed the Rank version to getRank().

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw some alternatives out there: I would perhaps model the value of a rank differently. Since the `ace` doesn't really have a definite value. A `Hand` has a value, but even that actually has a "best value", that may count an `ace` 11 or 1.

So I would perhaps *remove* the value of a rank. And introduce a `Hand`:

```java
public class Hand {
    private Hand(Collection<Card> cards) {
        ...
    }

    private int calculateBestValue() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I would also not make the value calculation public. The `Hand` could "present" itself, so it can also say whether you have a "soft" value or not.

I also think the `Deck` should not have a `getDeck()` method. That violates encapsulation. Instead it should a method called: `nextCard()`. Which gives you the next card from the top of the deck. It may need an `isEmpty()` method too, which returns whether the deck has cards or not.